# How to convert column name of highest values to row values based on highest value between all columns?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table generated in Oracle:

| field_x | field_y | watermelon | orange | cabbage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| lorem | ipsum | 4 | 2 | 5 |
| dolor | sit | 9 | 0 | 7 |
| amet | elit | 6 | 9 | 1 |

I wish to change it to the following:

| field_x | field_y | fruit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| lorem | ipsum | cabbage |
| dolor | sit | watermelon |
| amet | elit | orange |

Basically, the three last column names consolidate into a column based on whichever of the rows they have max value in (row 1 had max cabbage, row 2 had max watermelon, and row 3 had max orange). Keep in mind if one of the columns has a max, it should be overridden by the max of another column, if the other column's max is the highest (see watermelon and cabbage in 2nd row).

I suppose a "CASE" statement is possible, but I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to do so, as well.

Comment: What happens in the cases where there is a tie between multiple "fruits"? In your real data is there more then 3 "fruits"? How many is that?

Comment: Never thought of that, interesting case. I have no idea.

Comment: Well it's your set of requirements. Perhaps a comma separated list of tied "fruits"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT field_x,
       field_y,
       CASE
       WHEN watermelon = GREATEST(watermelon, orange, cabbage)
       THEN 'watermelon'
       WHEN orange = GREATEST(watermelon, orange, cabbage)
       THEN 'orange'
       WHEN cabbage = GREATEST(watermelon, orange, cabbage)
       THEN 'cabbage'
       END AS fruit
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (field_x, field_y, watermelon, orange, cabbage) AS
SELECT 'lorem', 'ipsum', 4, 2, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'dolor', 'sit',   9, 0, 7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'amet',  'elit',  6, 9, 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| FIELD_X | FIELD_Y | FRUIT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| lorem | ipsum | cabbage |
| dolor | sit | watermelon |
| amet | elit | orange |

If you can have multiple which are the maximum then:

```sql
SELECT field_x,
       field_y,
       SUBSTR(
         CASE
         WHEN watermelon = GREATEST(watermelon, orange, cabbage)
         THEN ', watermelon'
         END
         ||
         CASE
         WHEN orange = GREATEST(watermelon, orange, cabbage)
         THEN ', orange'
         END
         ||
         CASE
         WHEN cabbage = GREATEST(watermelon, orange, cabbage)
         THEN ', cabbage'
         END,
         3
       ) AS fruit
FROM   table_name
```

---

If you do not want to use a `CASE` expression, you could `UNPIVOT` and then aggregate (but it will be less efficient):

```sql
SELECT field_x,
       field_y,
       MAX(fruit) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY value) AS fruit
FROM   table_name
UNPIVOT (
  value
  FOR fruit IN (
    watermelon AS 'watermelon',
    orange     AS 'orange',
    cabbage    AS 'cabbage'
  )
)
GROUP BY field_x, field_y
```

| FIELD_X | FIELD_Y | FRUIT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| amet | elit | orange |
| dolor | sit | watermelon |
| lorem | ipsum | cabbage |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XIaASnFB)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use [MODEL](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/10g/r2/prod/bidw/sqlmodel/sqlmodel_otn.htm) clause:

```sql
Select  FIELD_X, FIELD_Y, SubStr(FRUIT, InStr(FRUIT, '_') + 1) "FRUIT"
From    (   Select  ROWNUM "RN", FIELD_X, FIELD_Y, CAST('xxx' As VarChar2(12)) "FRUIT",
                    WATERMELON, WATERMELON || '_WATERMELON' "F_1", 
                    ORANGE, ORANGE || '_ORANGE' "F_2", 
                    CABBAGE, CABBAGE || '_CABBAGE' "F_3"
            From    tbl
        )   MODEL   Partition By (FIELD_X, FIELD_Y)
                    Dimension By (RN)
                    Measures  (FRUIT, F_1, F_2, F_3, WATERMELON, ORANGE, CABBAGE) 
            RULES   (  
                       FRUIT[ANY] = GREATEST( F_1[CV()], F_2[CV()], F_3[CV()]  )  
                    )
```

... which with your sample data:

```sql
WITH
    tbl AS
        (
            Select  'lorem' "FIELD_X", 'ipsum' "FIELD_Y", 4 "WATERMELON", 2 "ORANGE", 5 "CABBAGE" From Dual Union All
            Select  'dolor' "FIELD_X", 'sit'   "FIELD_Y", 9 "WATERMELON", 0 "ORANGE", 7 "CABBAGE" From Dual Union All
            Select  'amet'  "FIELD_X", 'elit'  "FIELD_Y", 6 "WATERMELON", 9 "ORANGE", 1 "CABBAGE" From Dual 
        )
```

... results with:

```sql
FIELD_X FIELD_Y FRUIT      
------- ------- ------------
lorem   ipsum   CABBAGE      
dolor   sit     WATERMELON   
amet    elit    ORANGE
```

... for cases mentioned in MTO's comment - the model clause is very flexible so it could be adjusted to handle values from 10 above. In which case the RULES could be changed to check numerics:

```sql
RULES   (  
           FRUIT[ANY] = CASE GREATEST( WATERMELON[CV()], ORANGE[CV()], CABBAGE[CV()] ) 
                              WHEN WATERMELON[CV()] THEN F_1[CV()] 
                              WHEN ORANGE[CV()] THEN F_2[CV()]
                              WHEN CABBAGE[CV()] THEN F_3[CV()] 
                        END
        )
```

... the original answer (as stated) was for the sample data provided in the question. There could be more questions like what if two fruits have the same max value in the row? There could be more issues (as usualy are), but the model clause is very adjustable, fast and reliable.

Comment: This does not work [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/litqqhPj) as you are comparing the values alpha-numerically (where `'2'` > `'11'`) and not numerically (where `11` > `2`).

Comment: @MT0 You are right about numerics,  it's just that the answer was for the sample data provided (as stated). Anyway, added the RULES clause that covers it. There could be more issues that should be considered, but MODEL clause is usualy (not always, though) flexible enough to do the job.

Comment: I do not see what value the `F_1`, etc. columns add to the solution. You can simplify your code to [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TpR6jfIA) and then I wonder why you need the `MODEL` clause as you can include the `CASE` expression directly in the `SELECT` clause (as per my answer).

Comment: @MT0 There is no need for MODEL clause as there is no need for anything else it is just what it's said in the first line of the answer "One option is to use MODEL clause". Model clause is convenient for it's flexibility - nothing else. Other options are just like this one - they have good sides and bad  sides. Introducing the people different options should be good, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution using the `unpivot` and `row_number`

```
with frt as (
select 
  FIELD_X, FIELD_Y, FRUIT, VALUE,
  row_number() over (partition by FIELD_X, FIELD_Y order by value desc, FRUIT) rn
from tab
unpivot (
  value for fruit in (
    watermelon AS 'watermelon',
    orange     AS 'orange',
    cabbage    AS 'cabbage'
  ))  
)
select 
  FIELD_X, FIELD_Y, FRUIT
from frt
where rn = 1
```

In case you want to outpu talways onlyone value, this solution allows to controll the order  and the selection of the ties. See the `order by`  clause of the `row_number`

```
 order by value desc, FRUIT   --< this will select the lowest fruit (string) from the ties.
```

Also this query works in case that the *fruit* columns are nullable, where the solution with  Oracle `greatest` function will fail returning `null`.